# Close the infowindows of POI's in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

Is it possible to programmatically close the infowindows opened when a P.O.I has been clicked?  The reason I ask is that I only want one infowindow open at any one time.  At the moment, if I have a custom infowindow open and a P.O.I is clicked we have two windows open and it looks silly. Or, is it possible to detect the click on the P.O.I so I can then close the custom infowindow.  Or even disable the P.O.I click events entirely.

Thanks